# Website development: Architecture

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a site to display my comics- but I've read some tutorials ([Elated.com CMS design with images](http://www.elated.com/articles/add-image-uploading-to-your-cms/)) that advocate for using the database to store the file extensions, and use a more object oriented approach. I'm not doing that as of right now because I didn't see the need, as I manage files through FTP, and users won't be adding content. So, before I continue I'd like some peace of mind that my current architecture is okay.

Right now, My pages get images from the filesystem as such:

```
<?php
$dir = "../images/*";
foreach(glob($dir) as $image) {
$total = count(glob($dir . "*"));
?>
        <span class="comicBG"><a href="./viewComic.php?image=<?php echo $image ?>"><img src="./thumbnailer.php?img=<?php echo $image ?>&mw=&mh=" /></a></span>

<?php } ?>
```

Clicking on a comic displays that comic on a template:

```
<?php $myImage = $_GET['image']; ?>

 <center><img src="<?php echo  $myImage  ?>" /></center>
```

Can I continue on this way?

Thank you

Comment: If it suits your needs for now I don't see a reason why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely start that way but I guess it all depends on what your end goal is.  If you simply want to be able upload your comics to the /images/ directory and have the script display thumbnails and links, then you are good... but if you think you'll ever want more functionality than I would recommend at least working from a database.  For example it would be quite easy to store information about how many times each comic thumbnail was clicked on, or perhaps the screen resolutions of the people visiting and looking at the comics so you can then adjust the size of your comics accordingly.  Just a couple of ideas, but might be worth your time.

**EDIT:** Here is a sample table structure just to give you some ideas to start with.

```
cartoon_id           int(11)         auto-increment    primary
title                varchar(32)
filename             varchar(32)
description          varchar(256)
num_views            int(11)
last_view_dt         datetime
order                tinyint(3)
```

You could get fancy and setup a second table that you insert the view information into (date, time, ip_address, comic, etc) and could generate some fairly interesting stats.

Sample data would like the following:

```
cartoon_id:          1    (would be generated automatically)
title:               "Awesome Man!"
filename:            "images/cartoons/awesomeman1.jpg"
description:         "This was my first cartoon, created in 2002, etc..."
num_views:           2300  (this would setup to just auto increment when viewed)
last_view_dt         2012-07-21
order                1     (could use this to determine the order in which comics are displayed on the thumbnail page)
```

Could go on and on but I think you get the point.

Comment: thanks for your response. Storing info about the image is something I definitely plan on doing. Is this only achievable through a database?

Comment: @Growler: You can use your file-system as a database as well. You can also generate the html pages so you can cache a full gallery. In case you change the gallery, you just clear the cache and your scripts will re-generate the cache. The file-system works perfectly as a database for your type of application.

Comment: No - you could store it in text files, however the database is the way to go, and actually a fairly easy solution.  I assume your host has MySQL access?  I would ask them to set you up with a database and install yourself a copy of PHPMyAdmin and play around with it.  I'll edit my post with a sample table idea to get you started.

Comment: @LukePittman: Unless you don't have multiple editors for the galleries, you don't need a mysql database. Stop introducing things OP does not need and instead tell him how to prevent actual issues like XSS.

Comment: @LukePittman Thanks Luke. I actually started off my site using a MySQL database, but changed to filesystem when I found out how much overhead it was, especially with images. I'd like to see your example though.

Comment: @hakre Fair enough - I guess I just read his question more as "what are my options? where can I go? what can I do?" and thought I'd just give him a little insight to what is possible.  Additionally, I feel that a database is easier to work with for someone with less experience than trying to manage all of this the way your suggesting.  I guess its just opinion.

Comment: Options are only those which are practicable possible. The best image galleries I've created are file-based. That's because it's a format close to what a webserver does best and you can easily handle files in directories. Also it keeps things flexible, e.g. for site integrations. I'd first start to write an object oriented interface to the filesystem backend to get things going. That interface *could* be replaced with a database backend later on, if needed.

Comment: I agree that working from the file-system has its merits.  However in my response I was more discussing what is possible in the future, in particular with options like keeping track of user activity, setting orders, attaching descriptions or more information to the comics and so on. From my experience doing that with a file-system based approach is much more work than using a database.  Plus, it doesn't sound like this OP has the experience to being writing an OO interface to a file-system backend, whereas it would be easy with the plethora of tutorials online to tackle it using a database.

Answer (score 1):

Looks ok so far, you might want to validate the contents of `$_GET['image']` before you use it and want to take care that `$image` and `$myImage` are properly encoded when you output it. So basically taking care of output and input a bit more.

Additionally you don't use the `$total` variable, so it's not needed that you create it.

```
<?php
$dir = "../images/*";
$images = glob($dir);
foreach ($images as $image) {    
    $linkUrl = sprintf('./viewComic.php?image=%s', urlencode($image));
    $thumbUrl = sprintf('./thumbnailer.php?img=%s&mw=&mh=', urlencode($image))
    printf('<span class="comicBG"><a href="%s"><img src="%s" /></a></span>', $linkUrl, $thumbUrl);
}
?>
```

For input validation you should define a safe set of characters that are allowed in an image name and then check against it:

```
<?php
$image = $_GET['image']; 
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_-]+\.jpg$/')) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
    echo 'Forbidden'; 
    return;
}
?>
<center><img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($image) ?>" /></center>
```